# Finding the addends behind an output series.

Tags: combinatorics, natural-numbers

Let's imagine that we have a series of output, say, scores $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n \in \mathbb{N}$. We know that these scores are the result of addition of natural numbers, such that the highest score is the sum of *every number*. How do we find the constituent set of numbers?

An example: We have the output $O=\{0,2,3,4,5,7\}$. Everyone of these numbers can be written as a sum of the form $S=2s_1+2s_2+3s_3$ with $s_i \in\{0,1\}$. But how do we find $s_1,s_2,s_3$ from the output set?

Comment: This is, if I understand you correctly, non-unique. Is that a feature you want? Take $2 = 2\times 0 + 2\times 1 + 3\times 0 = 2\times 1 + 2\times 0 + 3\times 0$.

Comment: Without loss of generality it suffices to ask how to write *one* whole number as a sum of given integer weights no? Given such a process, simply apply the process to each score individually. Unless the weighted sum representations for the scores are *dependent* on each other in some fashion... By the way, you say we know the last score is the sum of all the weights - is there anything else we know about the scores?

Comment: Thank you for your comments for clarification. I was thinking of the output as possible scores on a test. The addends then represent the weight of the individual questions (obv. one could imagine non-integer weights of questions). As such, uniqueness is not required, @Raskolnikov.